# How can I resolve Bootstrap Datetimepicker issue?

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker in my module. Bootstrap datetimepicker is automatically displaying current date and time in text box. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You could play with the demo here http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any Javascript on your page that looks like this?

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", someDate);
$("#datepicker").datepicker('update');
```

If you removed that it should then show an empty textbox when your page loads

Comment: This script is applying a default date to your datepicker. If you dont want this then you need to remove this code...